# AutoMapper map object to any inherited destination type

Tags: c#, automapper-2

lets have an DTO class:

```
public class UserDto {
  public int Id { get;set; }
}
```

And viewmodel class (base mvc project library):

```
public abstract class UserViewModelBase {
  public int Id { get;set; }
}
```

now when i create mapping for automapper like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, UserViewModelBase>();
```

in main web mvc project i have concreate implementation of UserViewModelBase, like this:

```
public class UserViewModel: UserViewModelBase {
}
```

Now when i call this:

```
Mapper.Map<UserDto, UserViewModel>()
```

it fails with such error:

**Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.**

**UserDto -> UserViewModel**

As i understand that this was caused that i havent defined direct mapping between UserDto and UserViewModel. 
I want to know if there is some way how to tell AutoMapper that with this map `Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, UserViewModelBase>();` it should accept any type as destination type which inherits from `UserViewModelBase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no one knows how to achieve this so i made workaround for this.

My workaround was to build mappings (using `Mapper.CreateMap(...)`) multiple times each with concreate target class like:

in ClassLibrary1:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, UserViewModel1>();
```

in second ClassLibrary2:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, UserViewModel2>();
```

even if UserViewModel1 and UserViewModel2 is derived from same base class `UserViewModelBase`.

Comment: If anyone found other native AutoMapper functional solution i will mark that answer as accepted.